# JavaScript string comparison fails in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, string-comparison

I'm comparing two strings. For some reason no matter how I try to compare them, it appears as if they're not equal but they are.

```
logger.trace("eval Str: "+util.inspect(evalStr));
logger.trace("Is next():" + evalStr == "next()");
logger.trace("Is next():" + evalStr.valueOf() == "next()".valueOf());
logger.trace(toHex(evalStr));
logger.trace(toHex("next()"));

2016-10-02T12:10:55.446-04:00 - trace: eval Str: 'next()'
2016-10-02T12:10:55.447-04:00 - trace: false
2016-10-02T12:10:55.448-04:00 - trace: false
2016-10-02T12:10:55.448-04:00 - trace: 6e6578742829
2016-10-02T12:10:55.449-04:00 - trace: 6e6578742829


function toHex(str) {
    var hex = '';
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `+` in the `trace` calls, you're not comparing what you think you're comparing. You want to add explicit `()` so you're grouping the way you want to group:

```
logger.trace("Is next():" + (evalStr == "next()"));
// Note --------------------^-------------------^
```

Why:

Your original code:

```
logger.trace("Is next():" + evalStr == "next()");
```

...is evaluated like this:

```
logger.trace(("Is next():" + evalStr) == "next()");
// Note -----^----------------------^
```

...which is why you're not seeing `Is next():` in the output. `"Is next():next()" == "next()"` is false, so... :-)

---

And `==` or `===` are the correct way to compare strings in JavaScript. If both operands are strings, it doesn't matter which you use. If either of the operands may or may not be a string, use `==` if you want the abstract equality conversion rules (which are complicated) or `===` if you want the comparison to be false when the operands aren't the same type.